# MySQL, ajuda para entender exportação de dados

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Antigamente quando eu exportava um banco de dados ficava assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `config` (
  `ID_Config` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_site` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thema` char(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Config`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

> O auto_incremente e primary key ficavam direto no comando CREATE.

Agora quando eu exporto fica assim:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `config` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `versao` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sitemodelo` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

--
-- Indexes for table `config`
--
ALTER TABLE `config`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `config`
--
ALTER TABLE `config`
MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Uma class que achei na internet `class.leitor_sql.php` não lê o restante dos comandos, somente o que esta dentro do `CREATE`.

**Pergunta:**
Existe uma forma de mudar a configuração de exportação do mysql no phpMyAdmin?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você sabe o que foi alterado para ele começar a gerar o export diferente?

Comment: @Ricardo Acredito que seja a versão, pois mudou sozinho.

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no template da exportação. O PhpMyAdmin lhe oferece diferentes tipos de exportações, como `__DB__` e `__TABLE__`, por exemplo. Cada template trás um formato diferente. O segundo formato está para `__DB__`, se não me engano, pois ele trás primeiro todas as tabelas e depois todos os registros. Se na definição de tabela ele trouxesse auto_increment pré-configurado, as inserções que viriam no final do arquivo não começariam com o número 1.

Para obter o primeiro modelo, acredito que você deve exportar somente a estrutura das tabelas e não a base inteira.

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que a segunda forma gera uma consistência de dados.

O comando `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` criará uma nova tabela caso não exista.

Então, nesse momento pode ocasaionar em conflito de dados caso o auto_increment da tabela existente seja diferente da tabela que está importando.

Por isso existe a alteração do schema da tabela em seguida, separadamente do comando `CREATE`.

Utilize um importador de comandos SQL que suporte o reconhecimento de múltiplas queries. O próprio PHPMyAdmin, por exemplo.